# WooCommerce show random related products from other categories if product is in category with only one product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce product for which I would like to show four random related products from the store, because the product itself is alone in a category. I found this great script which almost works, but sometimes I get one, sometimes two, three, four related products on page reload. Any idea how to get a fixed number of four related products?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'filter_woocommerce_related_products', 10, 3 );
function filter_woocommerce_related_products( $related_posts, $product_id, $args ) {
    // Show products
    $show_products = 4;
    
    // Initialize
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    
    // When empty
    if ( empty( $related_posts ) ) {
        // Get WooCommerce product categories WP_Term objects
        $product_cats_ids = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy'  => $taxonomy,
            'fields'    => 'ids',
        ) );
        
        // Get product id(s) from a certain category, by category-id
        $product_ids_from_cats_ids = get_posts( array(
            'post_type'   => 'product',
            'numberposts' => $show_products + count( $args['excluded_ids'] ),
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'fields'      => 'ids',
            'tax_query'   => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'field'    => 'id',
                    'terms'    => $product_cats_ids,
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                )
            ),
            'orderby'     => 'rand',
            'exclude'     => $args['excluded_ids'],
        ));

        // Extract a slice of the array
        $related_posts = array_slice( $product_ids_from_cats_ids, 0, $show_products );
    }

    // Return
    return $related_posts;
}
```